# Booting Ubuntu 18.04 strange white/green/blue background

Tags: boot

After selecting Ubuntu in the Grub2 bootmenu, Ubuntu suddenly starts boot up, and the first enocounter is logo with a strange random background color. 
Later, the color changes to the original "normal".

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 version.

One of suspects https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth
As while these strange backgrounds appear, it is possible to press ESC button and get the log details of the boot.

How can this be traced and fixed?
I would like to not have these strange backgrounds even if they appear for 7-10 seconds.

Also, Ubuntu is installed on USB.
I plugged the same Ubuntu version into my Desktop computer, and there were no strange background change as it was with my laptop.

Could this be some kind of drivers problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try editing `/etc/default/grub` and change `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` to `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`. Then do `sudo grub-update`. Then type `reboot`. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: Did you mean `sudo update-grub`?
This command followed by error:
`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.`

After editing and applying your patch, nothing changed, no changes in booting can be seen.  

Double Checked. @heynnema

Comment: Oops. You're correct of course. That's what happens when you try and do this without my first cup of coffee :-) After doing the correct commands, you see **no** difference on the boot screen? Have you installed any video drivers? What video hardware do you have?

Comment: I haven't installed any drivers manually, 
This is the laptop's graphic's card: `AMD Radeon™ HD 7670M Graphics (2GB dedicated memory) ` I checked https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx But it seems that it is not compatible with little less powerful/older graphic cards, if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Also, I checked https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx there they noted that only `AMD Radeon™ HD7700/7800/8500/8600` are supported, I might need to give a try if `AMD Radeon™ HD 7670M ` could work with them

Comment: Installing Radeon drivers didn't fix anything related. https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: I think it is a problem with the driver and the graphics chip/card. See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13804718#post13804718)

Comment: There are limits with persistent live systems. If you install Ubuntu into the USB pendrive (I mean install like into an internal drive), you will have more possible solutions, all the tricks and tweaks, that work with an installed system. For example, the methods suggested by @heynnema are more likely to succeed, and you can try several boot options. This link may help, [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator) - step-wise instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

**Attempt at fix #1:**

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Then do

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

**Attempt at fix #2:**

Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and change

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Reboot and see if that helps.

**Attempt at fix #3:**

In `terminal`...

```
sudo update-initramfs -c
reboot
```

**Update #1:**

The user is appears to be running on a USB flash drive created with mkusb, with persistence... but they're not able to do fix #3... "read only file system" error. This fix won't work on a USB Live system.

Recommend installing Ubuntu on a standard HDD or SDD.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83912/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-booting-ubuntu-18-04-strange-white-green-blue-b).